# How to remove the Spreaded light?

Tags: photo-editing

I have a picture that blub light is (i don't know what to you this thing) is spreaded as you can see in the image. So how can i remove those spreaded light?

[image]

Full picture is in the link.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN4X8BvKaNh6OwJSiaD5Vg2pfCKP5A2XCmqOynrD-NJu8KDEQu9VC4ZlSV8arZn4g?key=ellENDRfOFJQUXItYXE5Y1pkOWN5N2dWclpna0Jn

Comment: Is cleaning the lens and re-shooting the picture an option? If yes, that would be MUCH easier than repairing the image in Photoshop.

Comment: you can use levels to exaggerate the moonbeams to the point of blowout, invert it,  then use that to make a mask. Run unsharp mask against the masked image (only affecting the moonbeams) at various settings (search for usm fog reduction) until  you see as much contrast in them as in the other areas. you will have to darken the masked image slightly too. Once that's done, remove the mask and clone the fixed moonbeams into the orig. It won't be perfect, but they will be a LOT less noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

Your lense is dirty. You'll need to carefully clean it with a lint free cloth, possibly with a little alcohol and de-ionized water, and then dry it.
You may also have grease/oil on the filter (check both sides) and / or the rear element.

To remove the bright light line, however, you're going to have to photoshop/have it retouched- or retake the photo with the clean surfaces.

Comment: It's not just dirty, it's oily. Human skin oil is the most likely culprit.

Comment: I've always generally used 'dirty' as 'oily' and 'dirt' and 'detritus', but you are correct- those long smears are caused by some sort of refractive mismatch most likely due to oil from the skin then 'wiped' across the surface by a cloth (i.e., shirt). Cleaning that off with dawn, alcohol, and DI water would work.